# Quotient of a coordinate ring by a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

The following question may be simple, but I tend to have bad intuition on the subject of algebra, so here goes:

Given a coordinate ring $R:=K[x_1,...,x_n]/\big( p_1,...,p_r \big)$ where $p_1,...,p_r \in K[x_1,...,x_n]$, and  a polynomial $q\in K[x_1,...,x_n]$, is it true that:

$R/\overline{q}\cong K[x_1,...,x_n]/\big( p_1,...,p_r, q \big)$

I think this statement is true by the correspondence theorem for ideals, but could not coherently state an argument to myself proving as much. I would also appreciate any counter-examples, if the original statement is incorrect.

Comment: For any ideals $I \subset J$ in a ring $A$, we have $(A/I)/(J/I) \cong A/J$. In your case, $A =K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, $I = (p_1,\dots, p_r)$ and $J=(p_1,\dots,p_r,q)$.

Comment: $R/q$ is a non-sense. You probably want to write $R/(\bar q)$, where $\bar q$ is the image of $q$ in $R$.

Comment: Yes I did mean it in that sense.  And "Parthiv Basu", could you write your comment as an answer, so I can tick this thread as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing the answer that Parthiv Basu wrote in the comments, so that I can tick this thread as closed (If my arguments are written incorrectly, feel free to edit):

Given a commutative ring $A$ with an ideal $I$, we know that for any ideal $J\supseteq I$ we have:

$A/J\cong \big(A/I \big)/ \big( J+I/ I \big)$ by the correspondece theorem for ideals.

In this case, for $A=K[x_1,...,x_n]$, $I=(p_1,...,p_r)$ and $J=(p_1,...,p_r,q)$, we have that $J+I=(\overline{q})$, and therefore:

$K[x_1,...,x_n]/J\cong R/(\overline{q})$